# Can we set NuGet URLs with domain policy

Tags: nuget, group-policy

NuGet is just great addition for Visual Studio. And it also allows for custom NuGet repositories as long as you provide custom URLs to them.

For company-related projects we can have own NuGet repositories serving whatever libraries are needed for internal projects. The main problem is that each developer has to configure this manually within Visual Studio.

### Question

Is it possible to set these URLs by domain security policy settings? This would be great, because every new team member that would install Visual Studio would automatically get these URLs and gettig project source code could automatically load related libraries (with the new NuGet feature that loads missing ones on build).

So @Haacked and Steve Sanderson... Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not yet possible. I'm pretty sure there's a feature request already for this in http://nuget.codeplex.com/. I recommend finding that feature and commenting on it. If you can't find it, start a discussion. :)

Comment: Thanks Phil. Exactly the kind of answer I'd like to hear. Well I'd rather hear that it's possible of course. But it's a direct and complete answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

NuGet 2.1 introduced hierarchical configuration settings for NuGet.  This allows you to specify things like additional repositories at a project/solution level rather than having to have everyone receive the settings through a group policy.

Release notes: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1

By setting a NuGet repository at the solution level, everyone working on the solution will get the additional repository added to their package sources.